# How to check if a particular value in a set?

Tags: apex, visualforce, code

I am taking input values from a CSV file using an Apex class. Whenever the currency code is null it's hitting validation error:

> **Currency ISO Code: invalid currency code: ". "**

So to handle that, I used `CurrencyIsoCode.getDescribe().getPicklistValues()`.

After using this it's not giving that validation error, but when I checked the debug log of what the String value is in the Set. However, it's taking the null value and entering into the else error logic in the code.

**In the Debug Logs**

> `String = USD SET= {AUD,USD,NZD}`

If I hardcode `String isocode = USD;` it works fine.

Part of the code:

```
String isoCode = Filevalues[3];
codesList.add(isoCode);
Set<String> validEntries = new Set<String>();

for (PicklistEntry entry : Quote__c.CurrencyIsoCode.getDescribe().getPicklistValues()){
    validEntries.add(entry.getValue());
}

for(String s: codesList){
    if(validEntries.contains(s)) // its returning false even though the USD is in set
    {
        check = true;
        ob.CurrencyIsoCode = currencyisoCode;
        System.debug('code' + ob..CurrencyIsoCode);
    }


    }
```

Comment: containsKey is a map method, try contains

Comment: Are you able to save your example ? you should get Compile Error:

Comment: @IlyaLepesh sorry its my mistake in my code it is contains

Comment: If the set contains String elements, the elements are case-sensitive. Two set elements that differ only by case are considered distinct. Make sure you comparing same values. Or use string.lowercase method

Comment: You may have trailing spaces in your CSV file and `FileValues[3]` is really `USD ` (length 4) - debug log won't show this.

Comment: @cropredy I see these values in debug logs::                                   21:57:03:883 USER_DEBUG [145]|DEBUG|input value 5:: AUD and 21:57:03:883 USER_DEBUG [146]|DEBUG|isocode ::AUD and DEBUG|Valid Entries ::{AED, ARS, AUD, BDT, BRL, CAD, CHF, CNY, COP, CZK, ...}

Comment: @cropredy As you said when I checked debugs the size of the isocode is different for each record, size String : 4 and for some its 9 and for others its 1 do i need to take only first 3 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `contains(setElement)`.

For more information, read [the `Set` class documentation.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm#apex_System_Set_contains)

Answer (score 1):

When using `String isoCode = Filevalues[3];`  it is retrieving empty spaces also

So to get rid of empty spaces I used trim() then its working fine.

```
String isoCode = Filevalues[3];
 String currcode = isoCode.trim();
if(validEntries.contains(currcode )){
                     ob.CurrencyIsoCode = currencycode;
                }
```

Comment: You should really accept your own answer...